# How can I create an index in on an array field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a **MongoDB** collection with data in the format of:

```
[
   {
      "data1":1,
      "data2":2,
      "data3":3,
      "data4":4,
      "horses":[
         {
            "opponent":{
               "jockey":"MyFirstName MyLastName",
               "name":"MyHorseName",
               "age":4,
               "sex":"g",
               "scratched":"false",
               "id":"1"
            },
            "id":"1"
         },
         {
            "opponent":{
               "jockey":"YourFirstName YourLastName",
               "name":"YourHorseName",
               "age":4,
               "sex":"m",
               "scratched":"false",
               "id":"2"
            },
            "id":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   ...
]
```

Executing the following query returns exactly what I need:

```
db.race_results.find({ "$and": [ { "horses": 
                        { "$elemMatch": { "$and": [
                            { "opponent.name": "MyFirstName MyLastName" },
                            { "opponent.jockey": "MyHorseName"}
                            ] } }
                        }
                      ]})
```

**However**, this query takes **0.5 seconds** to execute with my collection (there are a lot of records).

I am trying to find out how to create an index on the `horses.opponent.name` field of the data. I have read the docs about multikey indexes ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)), but I'm not sure if this is exactly what I need or not. What I need (I think) is an index on the array element of `horses`, but only the `name` and `jockey` fields. Is this possible?

**Is there a way to create an index to make my specific query (the one above) any faster?**

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to **MongoDB**, but learning fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index to create is:

```
db.race_results.ensureIndex({"horses.opponent.name":1, "horses.opponent.jockey":1})
```

After creating this index, the query in your case should return number of scanned objects that is equal to the number of matched objects:

```
db.race_results.find( { horses: { $elemMatch: { "opponent.name": "MyHorseName", "opponent.jockey": "MyFirstName MyLastName" } } }
).explain()
```